# Extending DOM elements

Tags: javascript

Im working on a jQuery/Zepto slider plugin and wanted ask you about extending dom elements.
I know that this method is not very elegant for different browsers environment but its make life so much easier.

Also to make names unique ive added all methods into one object 'pluginName'

So each slider item will get a set of custom methods:

```
item = document.createElement('div');
itemMethods(item); // add methods to item element

itemMethods = function(el){
 el.pluginName= {};
 el.pluginName.getIndex = function(){};
 el.pluginName.setLocalData = function(){};
 el.pluginName.getLoaclData = function(){};
}
```

Is this method worth a try? Are there any huge issues with custom element methods? Im not sure am i going to right direction. Thanks

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you are liable to get some memory leaks like this..

Comment: Since you mentioned jQuery, I suggest associating data with elements using `data()`

Comment: Since you're going to create an object every time you extend an element anyway, why not just make it an object wrapper like a jQuery object?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `document.createElement('div');` returns an instance of `HTMLDivElement`:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
console.log(div, div.constructor === HTMLDivElement);  // HTMLDivElement, true
```

Therefore, you can extend the `HTMLDivElement` class by simply adding properties to its `.prototype` object:

```
HTMLDivElement.prototype.pluginName = {};
HTMLDivElement.prototype.pluginName.getIndex = function () {};
HTMLDivElement.prototype.pluginName.getLocalData = function () {};
HTMLDivElement.prototype.pluginName.setLocalData = function () {};
```

Or even shorter:

```
HTMLDivElement.prototype.pluginName = {
    getIndex: function () {},
    getLocalData: function () {},
    setLocalData: function () {}
};
```

**EDIT**
If you just want to add new methods to a single div, try the following:

```
var itemMethods = function (el) {
    var index = 0;
    var data = {};
    el.pluginName = {
        getIndex: function () {
            // access the element by el
        },
        getLocalData: function () {
            // access the element by el
        },
        setLocalData: function () {
            // access the element by el
        }
    };
};

item = document.createElement('div');
itemMethods(item); // add methods to item element
```

Comment: The functions won't have any reference to the `div` element, which I would assume will be required. And it won't work in IE6/7, though that may not be an issue for OP.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What do you mean with no reference?

Comment: Inside the `getIndex` method for example, there will be no way to determine the `div` on which the method was called.

Comment: You're right, but I can't figure out a solution to this but adding these methods to `HTMLDivElement` instead of `pluginName`. Do you have  a suggestion?

Comment: That's about the only way *(adding them to `HTMLDivElement.prototype`)* that is. It would be nice if there was a way to reach back behind `plugin` name to get the object you want, but there just isn't any way to do it. Only other way would be to take advantage of closures like the OP is already doing. Though I'd be a little concerned about memory leaks like the commenter suggested.

Comment: I dont want to add new methods to all divs on a site. Only for a few slider items.

Comment: @Owl I'll fix my answer then.

Comment: @Owl: Is there a reason you don't just put the methods directly  on the your `div` elements?

Comment: How my method cause memory leaks?

Comment: @Owl: Lets say you're done with a `div` you've extended, so you drop your last reference to it. The garbage collector needs to see if there's any other reference before it can be destroyed. Well there is another reference *(assuming your methods are using `el`)*. So `el` has reference to `pluginname`, which has a reference to a method, which has a reference to `el`. Now it could be that modern JS engines can detect this circular reference, but I'd still be concerned. And it'll definitely be a leak in older IE.

Comment: @cookiemonster I know, I just wanted the show a cleaner way to do that :)

Comment: Thanks for an answer Cookie Monster. What if i remove that div from DOM. Are there still any leaks/references? BTW this is my plugin early version (dont have newst version live): http://owlgraphic.com/phenix/

Comment: @Owl: That's what I mean. If you remove it from the DOM, and you drop your last reference to it, you still have the circular reference I described above. Again, modern browsers may be able to cope with this. Not sure. Older IE will definitely leak though. A solution would be to make sure you always do `delete div.pluginName;` when you're done with it. But I'd personally just rather put the methods directly on the element so that they can use `this` instead of `el`. You'll just need to do `el = null;` at the bottom of `itemMethods` to help IE along.

Comment: Thanks Danilo for answer too! Will fix my code and make some test then ill add proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned jQuery, how about something like this:

```
var $div = $('<div/>').data({ 
    pluginName: { 
        doStuff: function(s){ console.log('hello ' + s); } 
    } 
});

$div.data('pluginName').doStuff('world');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LHk8j/

Comment: But then why not just create a jQuery plugin?

Comment: @cookiemonster It's up to OP if he want's to create a plugin or not. This is just to demonstrate how `data()` works

Comment: Sure, I just don't know why one would do it that way. I don't see the benefit, but I do see plenty of extra overhead.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I dont want use a data for each item (used it in my previous plugin and it works but looking for some native js solution)